# How can I figure out what questions will be on topic for a particular Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

*Is there a list somewhere, that explains which questions are appropriate in each of the Stack Exchange sites?*

Frequently, I'd ask a question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)/[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com)/[Super User](https://superuser.com/)/[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) et al., based on the site's similar questions, only to be notified by the site moderators that my question is inappropriate for their site.

How can I learn what can be asked about so that I can ask questions that won't be closed as off-topic?

Comment: I'm always happy when I see people trying to learn about the network and get better at using the site. I hope my edit stays in line of what you're trying to ask. Glorfindel's answer is a good one, and what I was in the process of drafting myself. It's not a bad idea for us to create a digest version of this somewhere but I think that knowing where to find it will be a good start for you. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @gnat That's hardly a guide to all of SE. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there's a [list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) where you see the taglines, e.g. Stack Overflow is "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers". Of course, that's not nearly detailed enough, and therefore all sites have their own version of the Help Center article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). To quickly go from one site's version to another, you only need to change the domain; the relative URL is always `/help/on-topic`.

Since we have a lot of sites where a computer science/programming question *might* be on-topic (depending on a lot of specifics), some of the users here have compiled these Help Center articles into a single FAQ: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/295232)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Glorfindel. I went through the URLs you mentioned, but still cannot figure out what (for example) is the difference between https://superuser.com/ and https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Well, broadly speaking, it's system administrator questions about software and hardware (Server Fault) vs. consumer questions about software and hardware (Super User). There will be some overlap, of course, but the *general* difference should really be clear from carefully reading (not skimming) the help center pages.